# colisionar mouse con un sprite

Tags: python, pygame

tengo problemas con hacer colisionar mi mouse con el sprite, eh estado usando el .isOver() junto a la posición del raton, pero con los sprite no puedo seleccionar, estoy probando con dibujando un cuadrado que siga al raton para hacer la colisión, el problema es que no se la forma de colisionar el cuadrado y el sprite al seleccionarlo, que puedo hacer?

aquí mi clase de los Sprite

```
class piedra(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self,n_piedra,x,y, estilo = ''):
    self.n_piedra = n_piedra
    self.estilo = estilo
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
def draw(self,venta,Spri = ''):
    imagen = pygame.image.load(Spri).convert()
    imagen.set_colorkey(NEGRO)
    venta.blit(imagen, [self.x,self.y])
```

con esta clase dibujo mi cursor

```
class Cursor(pygame.Rect):
   def __init__(self):
      pygame.Rect.__init__(self,0,0,1,1)
   def update(self):
      self.left,self.top = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

Cursor1 = Cursor()
```

como debería hacer la colisión en mi bucle?

```
    while Run:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             quit()
          if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            
            #captura la posición
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if Cursor1.collidedict(piedra1):
                pass
```

se me cae el programa al seleccionar mi esprite, (piedra1 es mi objeto piedra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar colliderect, pero para ello debes agregarle un self.rect a tu piedra, puedes hacerlo a partir de la imagen que le asignas:

```
self.rect = imagen.get_rect()
```

Asi, tambien puedes usar ese rect no solo para colisiones, sino tambien para dibujar la piedra, en lugar de:

```
venta.blit(imagen, [self.x,self.y])
```

Pones mejor:

```
venta.blit(imagen, self.rect)
```

Comment: Ya que estamos ;)
tu imagen tambien deberia ser self.imagen